# Showing some transformation is group isomorphism (topological group).

Tags: group-theory, topological-groups, group-homomorphism

Let's $Mg$ be a set of all real valued functions defined on topological group $G$. Assume that $f\in Mg$. Let's $a \in G$, then define $f_a(x):=f(ax)$ for all $x \in G$.
Now define $h_a(f):=f_a$ we know that $h_a:Mg \to Mg$.
Define $\varphi(a):=h_a$. We know, that this is isometry [For some fixed metric on $Mg$. AR], then denote group of all isometries of space $Mg$ into itself by $\operatorname{Is}(Mg)$.
I should show that $\varphi$ is a homomorphism of groups $G$ and $\operatorname{Is}(Mg)$.
But probably throught great number of signs i have had only bad ideas.
Please help.

Comment: I tried to correct misprints in your question. Check whether all is correct.

Answer (score 1):

To show that $\varphi$ is a homomorphism we have to check that $\varphi(ab)= \varphi(a)\varphi(b)$ for arbitrary $a,b\in G$. Since $\varphi(G)\subset\operatorname{Is}(Mg)$, we have to check that $\varphi(ab)(f)=\varphi(b)(\varphi(a)(f))$ for each function $f\in Mg$, that is that 
$(\varphi(ab)(f))(x)=(\varphi(b)(\varphi(a)(f)))(x)$ for each function $f$ and each element $x\in G$. This is true, because 
$$(\varphi(b)(\varphi(a)(f)))(x)=(\varphi(a)(f))(bx)=f(abx)=(\varphi(ab)(f))(x).$$